# Issue with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an application loadbalancer inside elastic beanstalk. I have an ec2 instance running php and apache. If I go to http://example.com I get the website. I have configured a socket server using node and socket.io on the same machine. ( This is installed and daemonized using .ebextensions and pm2 ). The socket daemon is running on port 8000.

I have added a `listener` for port 8000 inside the eb loadbalancer configuration. This auto created a `rule` with `listener port` 8000

The issue is when I go to http://example.com:8000 I get a response with the webpage just as if I went to http://www.example.com

I can stop the socket daemon and still load http://example.com:8000 which responds with the website. It seems like the loadbalancer is listening on port 8000 but routing it to the ec2 instance port 80

I would expect incoming requests on port 8000 to be forwared to the ec2 instance port 8000 which should be running my socket server but this not happening.

Here is the log output from the load balancer

```
http 2019-03-20T19:09:59.541171Z app/awseb-AWSEB-9GXN3SC7L5SW/e13ff49d239ea88e 
184.xx.xxx.xxx:58786 172.xx.xx.197:80 0.000 0.008 0.000 404 404 520 32879 
"GET http://www.example.com:8000/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=McSWbag HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" - - arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:xxxxxxxx:targetgroup/awseb-AWSEB-xxxxxx/xxxxxxx "Root=1-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx" "-" "-" 0 2019-03-20T19:09:59.532000Z "forward" "-" "-"
```

I'm not sure how the log reads but on the second line I notice: `172.xx.xx.197:80` that is the private ip of my ec2 instance and it is showing port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I needed to add a new `Process` that hits port 8000 and then configure the `Rule` to use that `Process`